# BufferedWriter no new line is printed

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I use:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\docum.txt"));
bw.write("Hello, world!\n");
bw.write("Hello!);
```

But it is printed `"Hello, world!Hello!"`, no `newline` is being printed. What should I do? thanks a lot

Comment: You're on Windows... use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: To make it work everywhere, `System.getProperty("line.separator")` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the carriage return

```
bw.write("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 5):

A newLine() method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator. Not all platforms use the newline character ('\n') to terminate lines. Calling this method to terminate each output line is therefore preferred to writing a newline character directly.

```
bw.newLine();
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: this is much better.